# What does this where Condition mean in python script

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to translate a python script into java. As I'm not much familiar with python, I cannot understand a condition in this script. here is the original script:

```
import numpy as np
def inverse_generalized_anscombe(x, mu, sigma, gain=1.0):        

    test = np.maximum(x, 1.0)
    exact_inverse = ( np.power(test/2.0, 2.0) +
                      1.0/4.0 * np.sqrt(3.0/2.0)*np.power(test, -1.0) -
                      11.0/8.0 * np.power(test, -2.0) +
                      5.0/8.0 * np.sqrt(3.0/2.0) * np.power(test, -3.0) -
                      1.0/8.0 - np.power(sigma, 2) )
    exact_inverse = np.maximum(0.0, exact_inverse)
    exact_inverse *= gain
    exact_inverse += mu
    exact_inverse[np.where(exact_inverse != exact_inverse)] = 0.0
    return exact_inverse
```

The line that I don't understand is this line:

```
exact_inverse[np.where(exact_inverse != exact_inverse)] = 0.0
```

As I understand, exact_inverse should be a single value, and not an array, so why is there a pair of square brackets in front of it? what is the condition in square brackets is trying to check? `exact_inverse != exact_inverse` condition seems to be always `false`, or am I missing something here.

The original Script can be found [here](https://github.com/broxtronix/pymultiscale/blob/master/pymultiscale/anscombe.py)

Comment: Instead of the `np.where(exact_inverse != exact_inverse)` one could also use `np.isnan(exact_inverse)` here.

Comment: Note that your question seems too broad. If I understand it correctly you're asking about (1) how NumPy operators and functions work (at least implicitly) (2) what the angle brackets mean (if you're interested google for "NumPy indexing") and (3) what the `exact_inverse != exact_inverse` means here. On StackOverflow you generally just ask one question per question so it's not only useful for you but also for future readers. I would encourage you to [edit] the question to just ask one question.

Comment: You state that you want to translate this script to Java - but that may not be possible. NumPy arrays are n-dimensional and the operations work element-wise (but can also broadcast). There may not be a general solution for this in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `(numpy.nan != numpy.nan) is True`, so, `exact_inverse != exact_inverse` is *not* always false.

Next, consider this:

```
>>> exact_inverse = 5
>>> exact_inverse += numpy.array([1,2]) # this may be 'mu', the same for 'gain'
>>> exact_inverse
array([6, 7]) # no longer an integer
```

Also, if `x` is an array, then:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> numpy.maximum(x, 1.0)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]) # that's an array!
```

And then, division, multiplication, addition, etc of arrays and numbers results in element-wise operations.